# Class<Test> object not the same type as a Test object? Junit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I'm trying to write some code which recursively adds TestSuites in a project to a suite of suites located at the root of the package hierarcy.

I've already written the code which returns a Collection object which contains a File object for each Test Suite found in my project.

I'm now trying to loop through them and add them to a TestSuite in a file called AllTests.java:

```
public static Test suite() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();

            //Code not included for getTestSuites() in this snippet.
    Collection<File> testSuites = getTestSuites();
    for(File f: testSuites) {

            //Truncate the path of the test to the beginning of the package name
            String testName = f.getAbsolutePath().substring(f.getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf("net"));

            //Replace backslashes with fullstops
            testName = testName.replaceAll("\\\\", ".");

            //Take the .class reference off the end of the path to the class
            testName = testName.replaceAll(".class", "");

            //Add TestSuite to Suite of Suites

            Class<? extends Test> test = (Class<? extends Test>) AllTests.class.getClassLoader().loadClass(testName);
            suite.addTest(test);
    }
```

Unfortunately I am getting the following compiler error on the suite.addTest(test) line:

> The method addTest(Test) in the type
>   TestSuite is not applicable for the
>   arguments (Class < capture#3-of ? extends Test>)

Am I making a fundamental mistake by assuming that a Class< Test > reference and a Test reference are one and the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are making a fundamental mistake by assuming that a Class< Test > reference and a Test reference are one and the same.

You need an **instance of a Class that extends `Test`**, not an instance of a Class object whose definition extends `Test` (Classes are objects too in java).

Answer (score 1):

`TestSuite.addTest` needs a Test class instance; not just a Class object.

You could try using `Class.newInstance()` if your tests can be (they should) instantiated without parameters.

--

A maybe better strategy is to start using Maven; which automatically runs all Test classes in the src/test/java source folder. But that can be a quite big overhaul :).

Answer (score 1):

`Class<Test>` describes the concept of class `Test` -- its fields, methods, and other stuff described by the Java code when defining class `Test`. There is *generally* (to keep classloaders out of this discussion) one instance of `Class<Test>` across the JVM, since there is basically just one `Test` class.

The same applies for every `Test` subclass -- there is generally one instance of `Class<TestSubClass>` for every `TestSubClass`.

On the other hand, there can be any number of `Test` objects.

Java allows you to create `Test` objects from a `Class<Test>`, by invoking `newInstance` against your `Class<Test>` instance. So basically, change your line from:

```
suite.addTest(test);
```

to

```
suite.addTest(test.newInstance());
```

And handle all potential exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for that. Have tried to use test.newInstance().suite() (To call the static suite() method on the object) but unforuantely I am getting a compiler error (correctly) stating that Test does not have  a suite() method. Unforuntately, neither does TestSuite(). I think I need to find a way to cast the test object to a type of Class<"Get the string out of my array and pump the name of the TestSuite in here"> - but I have no idea if that is even possible!

Comment: From the JavaDocs, I can see method `TestSuite.addTest(Test)` -- which means you can do `suite.addTest((Test) test.newInstance())`

Answer (score 0):

Method you are using expects instance of Test (sub)class.
The one you are after is probably addTestSuite(Class testClass) which allows adding classes.

Comment: I've tried that, but it comes back with Null errors saying that the Suite cannot find any tests in the child Suite. I've managed to get it working using suite.addTest(path.to.Suite.SuiteName.suite()) - now just trying to produce that line programatically :-)